# nodejs convert decimal to hex(00-00) and reverse?

Tags: node.js, hex

So I want to send a hex value to a service. The problem is that the service want this hex value in a specific format, 00-00, and also reversed.

For Example, when I want to tell the Service I want tag '1000':

1000 dec is `3E8` in hex. easy.
Now the service wants the format `03-E8`.
Also the service reads from right to left so the final value would be `E8-03`.

Another example, '3' would be `03-00`.

---

Edit:
I forgott to say that I dont need it as string, but as Uint8Array. So I would create the final result with `new Uint8Array([232, 3])`. (Eaquals `E8-03` = 1000)

So the question in general is: How can I get a [232,3] from an input of 1000 or [3, 0] from 3?

Is there a build in methode or a pakage that already can do this convertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any tool or package. I would do something like this:

```js
const a = 1000;

const a0 = a % 256;
const a1 = Math.floor(a / 256);

const arr = new Uint8Array([a0, a1]);

console.log(arr);
const arrStr = []
arr.forEach((elem) => {
  const str = elem.toString(16).toUpperCase();
  if (str.length === 2) {
    arrStr.push(str);
  } else {
    arrStr.push('0' + str)
  }
});

console.log(arrStr.reverse().join('-'));
```

Output:

```
Uint8Array(2) [ 232, 3 ]
03-E8
```

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a much simpler way, but here is a simple solution.

Edit: If you need at least two pairs, you can change the first argument of `padStart`.

```js
function dec2hexUi8Arr (n) {
    const hex = (n).toString(16);
    const len = hex.length;
    const padLen = len + (len % 2);
    const hexPad = hex.padStart(Math.max(padLen, 4), '0');
    const pairs  = hexPad.match(/../g).reverse().map(p => parseInt(p, 16));
    const ui8Arr = new Uint8Array(pairs);
    return ui8Arr;
}

const vals = [
  1000,
  3,
  65536
].map(dec2hexUi8Arr);

console.log (vals);
```

Comment: Thats pretty short, I like that. But I saw that if I try to convert `3` the result will be `[3]` and not `[3,0]` for the final result of `03-00`.

Comment: @sirzento Do you always need at least two pairs? What's the desired result if *n* is bigger than *65535* (FFFF) ?